# MayaVi: Label axes with "wrong" scale

Tags: scale, axes, mayavi, mayavi.mlab

Can I have a different scale on my axes than in my plot?

I'm displaying an image in mayavi, and then graphing some 3D shapes around it. All my measurements are related to the size of the image (ie in pixels) so that things are in the right relative positions.

But the image is of the Milky Way, and I want to label the axes in distance units (kpc) instead of pixels. Basically, I need to label the axes in pixels and then divide all the values by 20 to get kpc. Is that possible?

Thanks!